# Undo apt-get remove open* ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt

I am running a Linux instance on ec2, snap sorting of image is disabled.

While trying to un-install open-jdk from the system. I stupidly run the command

```
sudo apt-get remove open*
```

It started removing many packages, so I stopped the process by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I did it twice:

- `sudo apt-get remove open*`
- `sudo apt-get remove openjdk*`

I stopped the process (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) in between for both of them.

Now I see that my other application are not working, because of the packages removed.

Please advice, how can I go back to the state before apt-get remove.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure that apt-get informed you which package were be going to be removed.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the information about recently removed packages(What are all the packages that are recently removed) in `/var/log/dpkg.log` file along with the date and time.

```
awk '$3=="remove"' /var/log/dpkg.log
```

Find and reinstall the packages via `apt-get`.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the file `/var/log/dpkg.log`, you will see all operations regarding packages. So the list of removed packages can be retrieved from this log.

```
$ LIST=$(grep remove /var/log/dpkg.log|grep -v startup|grep open|awk '{print $4}')
$ sudo apt-get install $LIST
```

will build a list of package starting by *open* that were removed, put them in a shell variable and allow you to install them back in one shot.